Texstudio don't open
I installed the latest version of Texstudio on windows 10 and when I opened texstudio I got the message 
I tried to solve the problem by putting the dlls it claims it can't find in c:windows/System32 folder, but it didn't solve the problem.
Does anyone know how to solve this, I solved this problem on linux by installing md5, but on windows I don't know how to solve it, I welcome any suggestions.
Best regards
Benaia
